# powershell script -Extraction of strings between two characters

Tags: powershell

"aaaaaa,OU=DistributionGroups||bbbb,OU=SecurityGroups||cccc,OU=Groups||"

"eeeee,OU=FW||ffff,OU=Test||cccc,OU=vpn||"

Greetings
I have a .csv file with hundreds of lines (as shown in the example)
I need to extract all strings, for each line starting with OU = and ending with double ||

this is the desired result:

DistributionGroups

SecurityGroups

Groups

FW

Test

vpn

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Select-String -AllMatches` to find all occurrences of strings occurring between `OU=` and `||`:

```
$strings = Get-Content path\to\file.txt |Select-String 'OU=(.+?)\|{2}' -AllMatches |ForEach-Object {
    $_.Matches |ForEach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
} |Sort-Object -Unique
```

`$strings` will now contain the (unique) values extracted

Comment: Thanks it works!!!!

I can ask you for another info:

Now $strings contains the strings that interest me but many have the same name, to have a single value how can I do?

Now this is result :

SecurityGroups
DistributionGroups
DistributionGroups
SharedMailboxGroups
Groups
SharedMailboxGroups
SharedMailboxGroups
SharedMailboxGroups
SharedMailboxGroups
Progetti,
FW_Profiles,
FW_Profiles,
FW_Profiles,
Groups,
Groups,
Groups,
Progetti,
Groups,

Comment: @renatocilento `$strings = $strings |Sort-Object -Unique` should do the trick :)